# pass data from component to Teaching Bubble headlines

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react, reactjs

I am trying to pass data for headline from  my .tsx file to teaching bubble headline which is another  but getting below error

```
            import * as React from 'react';
            import { DefaultButton, IButtonProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
            import { ITravelBriefProps } from './ITravelBriefProps';
            import { TeachingBubble } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TeachingBubble';
            import { useBoolean } from '@uifabric/react-hooks';
            import styles from './TravelBrief.module.scss';
            import {
              getTheme,
              mergeStyleSets, 
              FontWeights,
              ContextualMenu,
              Toggle,
              //DefaultButton,
              Modal,
              IDragOptions,
              IconButton,
              IIconProps,ITeachingBubbleProps
            } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
            const iconButtonStyles = {
              alignItems: 'normal',
              root: {
                color: '#dd1d21',
                marginLeft: 'auto',
                marginTop: '2px',
                marginRight: '2px',
                
                
              },
              rootHovered: {
                color: '#dd1d21',
              },
            };

            const ArrowIcon: IIconProps = {  iconName: 'Feedback' };




            const examplePrimaryButtonProps: IButtonProps = {
              
              children: 'Yes',
              onClick: function () {
                location.href = " 
            }

            }

            const constheadline :ITeachingBubbleProps={

             headline:""

            }



            export const TeachingBubbleBasicExample: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
              const [teachingBubbleVisible, { toggle: toggleTeachingBubbleVisible }] = useBoolean(false);
              

              const exampleSecondaryButtonProps: IButtonProps = React.useMemo(
                () => ({
                  children: 'Maybe later',
                  onClick: toggleTeachingBubbleVisible
                  
                }),
                [toggleTeachingBubbleVisible],
                   
              );

               return (
                <div>
                  <div> <IconButton
                        styles={iconButtonStyles}
                        iconProps={ArrowIcon}
                        ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
                        onClick={toggleTeachingBubbleVisible}
                        id="targetButton"
                    text={teachingBubbleVisible ? 'Hide TeachingBubble' : 'Show TeachingBubble'}
                      />  <label className={styles.label} onClick={toggleTeachingBubbleVisible} ></label> 
            </div>
            {/*       <DefaultButton
                    id="targetButton"
                    onClick={toggleTeachingBubbleVisible}
                    text={teachingBubbleVisible ? 'Hide TeachingBubble' : 'Show TeachingBubble'}
                  /> */}

                  {teachingBubbleVisible && (
                      
                    <TeachingBubble
                      target="#targetButton"
                      // primaryButtonProps={examplePrimaryButtonProps}
                      // secondaryButtonProps={exampleSecondaryButtonProps}
                      onDismiss={toggleTeachingBubbleVisible}
                      header="Test"
                      
                    >
                

              

                    </TeachingBubble>

                    

                  )}

                </div>
              );
            };


            import * as React from 'react';
            import styles from './TravelBrief.module.scss';
            import { useId, useBoolean } from '@uifabric/react-hooks';
            import {
              getTheme,
              mergeStyleSets, 
              FontWeights,
              ContextualMenu,
              Toggle,
              //DefaultButton,
              Modal,
              IDragOptions,
              IconButton,
              IIconProps
            } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
            import { TeachingBubble } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TeachingBubble';
            import { DefaultButton, IButtonProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
            import { ITravelBriefProps } from './ITravelBriefProps';
            import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
            import { IStackTokens, Stack } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Stack';
            import {
              DocumentCard,
              DocumentCardActivity,
              DocumentCardTitle,
              DocumentCardLogo,
              DocumentCardStatus,
              IDocumentCardLogoProps,
              IDocumentCardActivityPerson,
              IDocumentCardStyles,
            } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DocumentCard';
            import { mergeStyles } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Styling';
            import * as jquery from 'jquery';
            import {TeachingBubbleBasicExample} from './Teaching';
            import { Dropdown, DropdownMenuItemType, IDropdownStyles, IDropdownOption } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dropdown';
            import { data } from 'jquery';
            import Rating from 'react-rating'; 
             
            import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';    
            SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'); 
            var text=""

            const dropdownStyles: Partial<IDropdownStyles> = {
              dropdown: { width: 172},
            };
              const logoProps: IDocumentCardLogoProps = {
                logoIcon: 'Video',
              };
              const logoProps2: IDocumentCardLogoProps = {
                logoIcon: 'CRMCustomerInsightsApp',
              };
              const logoProps3: IDocumentCardLogoProps = {
                logoIcon: 'Hospital',
              };
              const logoProps4: IDocumentCardLogoProps = {
                logoIcon: 'Taxi',
              };
              const logoProps5: IDocumentCardLogoProps = {
                logoIcon: 'MapPin',
              };
              const logoProps6: IDocumentCardLogoProps = {
                logoIcon: 'WebAppBuilderFragmentCreate',
              };
            const cardStyles: IDocumentCardStyles  = {
              root: [
                {
                  display: 'inline-block',width: 60,marginRight: 20,  marginBottom: 20,
            backgroundColor:"white", outline:'none',borderStyle:'solid',border:0,borderColor:'#fbce07',textAlign: "center" ,color:"white",borderWidth:"thin",
            selectors: {
              
                 ':hover': {
                  backgroundColor:'#fbce07' ,outline:'none',borderColor:'#fbce07'   },
                
              ':after': {
                color: 'transparent',
                content: '',
                display: 'block',
                height: '1px',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                visibility: 'hidden'
              },
              ':before': {
                color: 'transparent',
                content: '',
                display: 'block',
                height: '1px',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                visibility: 'hidden'
              }, 

            }
                }
              ]
            };



              const dragOptions: IDragOptions = {
                moveMenuItemText: 'Move',
                closeMenuItemText: 'Close',
                menu: ContextualMenu,
              };

              const theme = getTheme();
              const contentStyles = mergeStyleSets({
                container: {
                  display: 'flex',
                  flexFlow: 'column nowrap',
                  alignItems: 'stretch',
                },
                header: [
                  // eslint-disable-next-line deprecation/deprecation
                  theme.fonts.xLargePlus,
                  {
                    flex: '1 1 auto',
                    borderTop: `4px solid ${theme.palette.themePrimary}`,
                    color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    fontWeight: FontWeights.semibold,
                    padding: '12px 12px 14px 24px',
                  },
                ],
                body: {
                  flex: '4 4 auto',
                  padding: '0 24px 24px 24px',
                  overflowY: 'hidden',
                  width:'600px',
                  selectors: {
                    p: { margin: '14px 0' },
                    'p:first-child': { marginTop: 0 },
                    'p:last-child': { marginBottom: 0 },
                  },
                },
              });
              const toggleStyles = { root: { marginBottom: '20px' } };
              const iconButtonStyles = {
                alignItems: 'normal',
                root: {
                  color: '#dd1d21',
                  marginLeft: 'auto',
                  marginTop: '2px',
                  marginRight: '2px',
                  
                  
                },
                rootHovered: {
                  color: '#dd1d21',
                },
              };
            const cancelIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'Cancel' };
            const ArrowIcon: IIconProps = {  iconName: 'FlickLeft' };
            const PrintIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'Print' };
            const DownArrowIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'Flickup' };
            const CircleIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'Circle' };



            const conversationTileClass = mergeStyles({ height: 90 });

            const conversationTileClass1 = mergeStyles({ height: 40 });

            export interface CountryTravel{ 
                isModalOpen: boolean,
                showModal:boolean,
                hideModal:boolean,
                items:any[],
                decription:string,
                ddlCountry:any[],
                isDataLoading: boolean,
                itemsTravelTo:any[],
                open:boolean,
                ToggleIcon:boolean,
                ToggleIconBooking:boolean,
                openBooking:boolean,
                TeachingBubble:string,
                Countryto:string,
                RatingMatrix:number,
                ToggleIconEmergencyContact:boolean,
                ToggleIconTipsSaferTravel:boolean,
                ToggleIconHealth:boolean,
                 parentInput:string,
                 childData: string

              } 

              interface IntrinsicElements {
                foo: any;
              }
             

            export default class TravelBrief extends React.Component<ITravelBriefProps, CountryTravel> {

              private _dropdown: IDropdownOption[]; 

              state: CountryTravel

              constructor(props: ITravelBriefProps)
            { 
            super(props);


            this.state = 
            {
              isModalOpen: false,
              showModal:false,
              hideModal:false,
              items:[],
              decription:'',
              ddlCountry:[],
              isDataLoading: false,
              itemsTravelTo:[],
              open:false,
              ToggleIcon:false,
              openBooking:false,
              TeachingBubble:'',
              ToggleIconBooking:false,
              Countryto:"",
              RatingMatrix:5,
              ToggleIconEmergencyContact:false,
              ToggleIconTipsSaferTravel:false,
              ToggleIconHealth:false,
              parentInput:"",
              childData:""
              

            }
            this.handleCallbak = this.handleCallbak.bind(this);
            }

            private handleCallbak(childData: string): void {
              this.setState({
                childData: childData
              });
            }


            private _toggle = (openk) => {
              this.setState({  open:!this.state.open});
              
            };

            private _OpenPanel = (open) => {
              this.setState({  showModal:true  });
              this.setState({  isModalOpen:true  });
             
            };

            private _OpenBooking = (openBooking) => {
              this.setState({  openBooking:!this.state.openBooking});
             
            };
             

            private _hidePanel = () => {
              this.setState({  showModal:false  });
              this.setState({  isModalOpen:false  });
              this.setState({ToggleIconEmergencyContact:false,ToggleIconTipsSaferTravel:false,ToggleIconHealth:false})
              
            };

            myColor (statuscolor)
            {
              if(statuscolor=="High")
              {
                //this.setState({RatingMatrix:5})
                return "red"
                
              }
              if(statuscolor=="Low")
              {
                //this.setState({RatingMatrix:2})
                return "orange"
              }
              if(statuscolor=="Medium")
              {
               // this.setState({RatingMatrix:3})
                return "orange"
              }

              if(statuscolor=="Extreme")
              {
                //this.setState({RatingMatrix:5})
                return "black"
              }

              
             
            }

            myColorImage (statusimage)
            {
              if(statusimage=="High")
              {
                //this.setState({RatingMatrix:5})
                return ""
                
              }
              if(statusimage=="Low")
              {
                //this.setState({RatingMatrix:2})
                return ""
              }
              if(statusimage=="Medium")
              {
               // this.setState({RatingMatrix:3})
                return ""
              }

              if(statusimage=="Extreme")
              {
                //this.setState({RatingMatrix:5})
                return ""
              }

              
             
            }

            private DataBind(a,b)
            {
              //this.setState({Countryto:a})
              var reactHandler = this;
              jquery.ajax({
              url: `${reactHandler.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Country Travel Brief')/items?$orderby=ID asc&$filter=CTCountry eq '${a}' `,
              type: "GET",
              headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'},
              success: function(resultData) {  
              if(b=='TravelTo')
              {        
              reactHandler.setState({
              items: resultData.d.results,
              });
            }
            else
            {
              reactHandler.setState({
              itemsTravelTo: resultData.d.results[0]
              });
            }
              console.log(reactHandler.state.itemsTravelTo)
              
              } ,
              error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              }
              });
              

            }



            public  SelectReferralFromQueryString(){

            var url_string = window.location.href
            var url = new URL(url_string);
            var Countryurl = url.searchParams.get("Country");
            this.setState({Countryto:Countryurl})
            this.DataBind(Countryurl,'TravelTo')

            }
            private GetParameterValues(param) {
            var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
                var urlparam = url[i].split('=');
                if (urlparam[0] == param) {
                    return urlparam[1];
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
            }

            public PrintContent()
            {
            var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('PrintHead');
            var WindowObject = window.open("", "PrintWindow",
            "width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");
            WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
            WindowObject.document.close();
            //setTimeout(function(){
                WindowObject.focus();
                WindowObject.print();
                WindowObject.close();
            //},6000);
            }


            public componentDidMount()
            {
            var reactHandler = this;
            var currentuser ='';
            var Show='Yes';
            var _ddlCountry: IDropdownOption[] = []
            jquery.ajax({
            url: `${reactHandler.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Country Travel Brief')/items?$orderby=ID asc&$Select=CTCountry `,
            type: "GET",
            headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'},
            success: function(resultData) {
              if (resultData.d.results.length > 0) {

                for (var i = 0; i < resultData.d.results.length; i++) {
                  var odata = resultData.d.results[i];
                  _ddlCountry.push({
                    key: odata.CTCountry,
                    text: odata.CTCountry,

                  }); console.log(_ddlCountry)

                }
                reactHandler.SelectReferralFromQueryString()

                reactHandler.setState({ ddlCountry: _ddlCountry })
               // reactHandler.DataBind(_ddlCountry)   
              }  

            } ,
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
            });

            }
             
              public render(): React.ReactElement<ITravelBriefProps> {
                
                return (

                  <div className={ styles.travelBrief }>
                    
                    <Modal
                  //  titleAriaId={titleId}
                    isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
                    onDismiss={this._hidePanel}
                    
                    isBlocking={false}
                    containerClassName={contentStyles.container}
                    //dragOptions={isDraggable ? dragOptions : undefined}
                  >
                    <div className={contentStyles.header} id={"ModalHead"}>
                      <IconButton
                        styles={iconButtonStyles}
                        iconProps={cancelIcon}
                        ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
                        onClick={this._hidePanel}
                      />    &nbsp; &nbsp;  
                         <IconButton iconProps={PrintIcon} onClick={() => this.PrintContent()}></IconButton> 
                    </div>
                    <div className={contentStyles.body} id={"PrintHead"}>
                    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.decription}}></p>
                    </div>

                  </Modal>
                    <div className={ styles.container }>
                    <div className={ styles.header}>
                    <div>
                      <div className={styles.headerlogo}>
                    <div>
                    <a title="Homepage" href=">
                    <img className={styles.Logo}  src=""/></a>
                   </div></div>
                   <div>
                   <div className={styles.headertxt} >
                  <h3 className={styles.headstyle} >CORPORATE TRAVEL</h3>
                  <h6 className={styles.subheadstyle} > SEAMLESS AND SAFE</h6>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                 </div></div>
                      <div className={ styles.row }>
                      
                        <div className={ styles.column }>
                          <div>
                            <div className={styles.Dropdown}>
                        <Dropdown
                    placeholder="Select an option"
                    //selectedKey={this.SelectReferralFromQueryString(name)}
                    label="TRAVELLING TO"
                    options={this.state.ddlCountry}
                    selectedKey={this.state.Countryto}
                    styles={dropdownStyles}
                    onChange={(_, optionSelected) => {this.DataBind(optionSelected.key,'TravelTo');
                    }}
                  /></div>
              <div className={styles.matrix}>
              <table>
              <tr>
                <th>HEALTH</th>
                <th>SECURITY</th>
                <th>ROAD SAFETY</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
            {/*   {this.state.items.length!=0?<img src={this.myColorImage(this.state.items[0]['CTRoadSafety'])}></img>:''}
              {this.state.items.length!=0?<img src={this.myColorImage(this.state.items[0]['CTRoadSafety'])}></img>:''}
              {this.state.items.length!=0?<img src={this.myColorImage(this.state.items[0]['CTRoadSafety'])}></img>:''}  */}    
               {this.state.items.length!=0?<td> <img width={100} src={this.myColorImage(this.state.items[0]['CTHealth0'])}></img></td>:''}
               {this.state.items.length!=0?<td> <img width={100} src={this.myColorImage(this.state.items[0]['CTSecuirty0'])}></img></td>:''}

               {this.state.items.length!=0?<td> <img width={100} src={this.myColorImage(this.state.items[0]['CTRoadSafety'])}></img></td>:''}
               </tr> <tr>
               {this.state.items.length!=0?<td>{this.state.items[0]['CTHealth0']}</td>:''}
               {this.state.items.length!=0?<td>{this.state.items[0]['CTSecuirty0']}</td>:''}

               {this.state.items.length!=0?<td>{this.state.items[0]['CTRoadSafety']}</td>:''}
               

              </tr>
            </table>

            </div></div>

            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

             <div> 
             

                      {this.state.items.map((post,key) =>
                      <div className={styles.containers}> 
                    
                      <DocumentCard
                      className={styles.levelcontainer}
                     onClick={() =>{this._OpenPanel(this.setState({ decription:post.CTSecuirty}))}}
                     >
                    <DocumentCardLogo {...logoProps} className={styles.thumbnailimg} />
                    <div className={styles.overlayFirst}>
                    <DocumentCardTitle
                        title={
                          'SECURITY'
                        }
                        shouldTruncate
                        showAsSecondaryTitle  className={styles.overlaycontentFirst}
                      /></div>
                  </DocumentCard>
                  

                
                  <DocumentCard
                   className={styles.levelcontainer}
                    //onClick={this.Dialog('')}
                    onClick={() =>{this._OpenPanel(this.setState({ decription:post.CTTravelAlert}))}}
                  >
                    <DocumentCardLogo {...logoProps2} className={styles.thumbnailimg} />
                    <div className={styles.overlayFirst}>
                      <DocumentCardTitle
                        title={
                          'TRAVEL ALERT'
                        }
                        shouldTruncate
                        showAsSecondaryTitle  className={styles.overlaycontentFirst}
                      /></div>
                   
                   
                  </DocumentCard>

                  <DocumentCard
                  className={styles.levelcontainer}
                    //onClick={this.Dialog('')}
                    onClick={() =>{this._OpenPanel(this.setState({ decription:post.CTSafety}))}}
                  >
                    <DocumentCardLogo {...logoProps3} className={styles.thumbnailimg} />
                    <div className={styles.overlayFirst}>
                      <DocumentCardTitle
                        title={
                          'SAFETY'
                        }
                        shouldTruncate
                        showAsSecondaryTitle  className={styles.overlaycontentFirst}
                      />
                   
                   </div>
                  </DocumentCard>

                  <DocumentCard
                    className={styles.levelcontainer}
                    //onClick={this.Dialog('')}
                    onClick={() =>{this._OpenPanel(this.setState({ decription:post.CTCommute}))}}
                  >
                    <DocumentCardLogo {...logoProps4} className={styles.thumbnailimg} />
                    <div className={styles.overlayFirst}>
                      <DocumentCardTitle
                        title={
                          'COMMUTE'
                        }
                        shouldTruncate
                        showAsSecondaryTitle  className={styles.overlaycontentFirst}
                      />
                   
                   </div>
                  </DocumentCard>

                  <DocumentCard
                    className={styles.levelcontainer}
                    //onClick={this.Dialog('')}
                    onClick={() =>{this._OpenPanel(this.setState({ decription:post.CTLoaction}))}}
                  >
                    <DocumentCardLogo {...logoProps5} className={styles.thumbnailimg} />
                    <div className={styles.overlayFirst}>
                      <DocumentCardTitle
                        title={
                          ' LOCATIONS'
                        }
                        shouldTruncate
                        showAsSecondaryTitle  className={styles.overlaycontentFirst}
                      />
                   
                   </div>
                  </DocumentCard>

                  <DocumentCard
                   className={styles.levelcontainer}
                    //onClick={this.Dialog('')}
                    onClick={() =>{this._OpenPanel(this.setState({ decription:post.CTOthers}))}}
                  >
                    <DocumentCardLogo {...logoProps6} className={styles.thumbnailimg} />
                    <div className={styles.overlayFirst}>
                      <DocumentCardTitle
                        title={
                          'OTHERS'
                        }
                        shouldTruncate
                        showAsSecondaryTitle  className={styles.overlaycontentFirst}
                      /></div>
                   
                   
                  </DocumentCard>


                      </div>     )}   
                
                </div>
                          
                          
                          
                          
                        </div>

                        <div className={ styles.column1 }>
                        {this.state.items.map((post,key) =>
                 <div>
                 <div> <IconButton
                        styles={iconButtonStyles}
                        iconProps={this.state.ToggleIconEmergencyContact?DownArrowIcon:ArrowIcon}
                        ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
                        onClick={() =>{this._OpenPanel(this.setState({ decription:post.CTEmergencyContacts}));this.setState({ ToggleIconEmergencyContact: !this.state.ToggleIconEmergencyContact })}}
                         label="test" />
                      <label className={styles.label}  onClick={() =>{this._OpenPanel(this.setState({ decription:post.CTEmergencyContacts}));this.setState({ ToggleIcon: !this.state.ToggleIcon })}}>EMERGENCY CONTACTS</label>  
                      </div>
                      
                <div > <IconButton
                        styles={iconButtonStyles}
                        iconProps={this.state.ToggleIconHealth?DownArrowIcon:ArrowIcon}
                        ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
                       // onClick={this._hidePanel}
                       onClick={() =>{this._OpenPanel(this.setState({ decription:post.CTTipSaveTravel}));this.setState({ ToggleIconHealth: !this.state.ToggleIconHealth })}}/>
                       <label className={styles.label} onClick={() =>{this._OpenPanel(this.setState({ decription:post.CTTipSaveTravel}));this.setState({ ToggleIcon: !this.state.ToggleIcon })}}>TIPS FOR SAFER TRAVEL</label>    
               </div>
              <div> <IconButton
                        styles={iconButtonStyles}
                        iconProps={this.state.ToggleIconTipsSaferTravel?DownArrowIcon:ArrowIcon}
                        ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
                        onClick={() =>{this._OpenPanel(this.setState({ decription:post.CTHealth}));this.setState({ ToggleIconTipsSaferTravel: !this.state.ToggleIconTipsSaferTravel })}}
                      /><label className={styles.label} onClick={() =>{this._OpenPanel(this.setState({ decription:post.CTHealth}));this.setState({ ToggleIcon: !this.state.ToggleIcon })}}>HEALTH</label>   
            </div>

            </div>
                  )}
                  <br></br>
                  
                  <br></br>
                  <br></br>
                  {this.state.items.length!=0?<TeachingBubbleBasicExample  data ={this.state.ddlcountry} />:''}

                 <br></br>
                  <br></br>
                  <br></br>
            <div>
               <div className={styles.matrix1}>  <span className={styles.labelhd}>TRAVELLING FROM</span></div>
                 <div className={styles.Dropdown1}>
                        <Dropdown
                    placeholder="Select an option"
                    label=""
                    options={this.state.ddlCountry}
                    styles={dropdownStyles}
                    onChange={(_, optionSelected) => {this.DataBind(optionSelected.key,'TravelFrom');
                    
                    }}
                  /></div></div>
                          <div> 
                          <IconButton
                        styles={iconButtonStyles}
                        iconProps={this.state.ToggleIcon?DownArrowIcon:ArrowIcon}
                        ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
                        onClick={(e) =>{this._toggle(e);this.setState({ ToggleIcon: !this.state.ToggleIcon })} }/> 
                        <label onClick={(e) =>{this._toggle(e);this.setState({ ToggleIcon: !this.state.ToggleIcon })} } className={styles.label}>VISA CONTACT</label>
                        {this.state.open?<p className={styles.label} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.itemsTravelTo['CTVisaContact']}}></p>:''}
                        </div>
                  
                           <div> <IconButton
                        styles={iconButtonStyles}
                        iconProps={this.state.ToggleIconBooking?DownArrowIcon:ArrowIcon}
                        ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
                        onClick={(e) =>{this._OpenBooking(e);this.setState({ ToggleIconBooking: !this.state.ToggleIconBooking })}} 
                        name="Test"
                       
                      /><label onClick={(e) =>{this._OpenBooking(e);this.setState({ ToggleIconBooking: !this.state.ToggleIconBooking })}}  className={styles.label}>ONLINE BOOKING</label>
                      {this.state.openBooking?<p className={styles.label} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.itemsTravelTo['CTOnlineBooking']}}></p>:''}
                      </div>
                        </div>
                        
                      </div>
                      <div>
            <div className={styles.blockColfoot}>
            <p className={styles.foot}>
            <b>

            </b></p></div></div>

                     

                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: What's the component TeachingBubbleBasicNext?I can not find it in office ui.

Comment: its TeachingBubblebasic

Comment: Whatis the type of ddlCountry in your code?The data needs a Array value.

Comment: ddl country is dropdown yes its array value

Comment: @Amos_MSFT i tried adding string but same error

Comment: It needs an Array value. I did not find TeachingBubblebasic component, so I could not do more test for you.

Comment: added teaching bubble component code

Comment: You did not include TeachingBubbleBasicNext in the code.

Comment: its TeachingBubbleBasicExample my screenshot showing wrong name which i taken while testing its should be {this.state.items.length!=0?<TeachingBubbleBasicExample data ={this.state.ddlcountry}/>:''}

Comment: What about state-related code? The code you shared seems to have nothing to do with the code you reported wrong.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience i added both code